# WP7 Silverlight - Change DataContext in runetime

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

how do I change the DataContext to another view model in runtime.
Now the data is not changed, after I run the click event:

```
    public PivotPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.TeamDocViewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = App.TaskViewModel;
    }
```

Some suggestions?

Comment: First I think you have a typo: App.TaskViewMode should be App.TaskViewModel. Second: Your code should work. There might be problem with binding in your xaml file, would be nie if you post it here. (Maybe you bind to submembers like "User.Name" and don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your models)

Comment: It builds just fine, and there is no error. It puts the first view model is also quite nice! But when I try to change the DataContext will not change the data, but display data even from the old model on view.

I wrote the wrong here, updated now.

Comment: What happens if you change DataContext = App.TaskViewModel; to DataContext = null; ?) Xaml is interesting to see.

Comment: Then it shows nothing, as expected.
BUT I went through all the view models now, and you were right! I had forgotten INotifyPropertyChanged in TeamDocViewModel, then say it's not from the UI that it's changed:) Thanks

Comment: Can you write it as an answer, so I will accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you have a typo: App.TaskViewMode should be App.TaskViewModel. Second: Your code should work. There might be problem with binding in your xaml file, would be nie if you post it here. (Maybe you bind to submembers like "User.Name" and don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your models)

What happens if you change DataContext = App.TaskViewModel; to DataContext = null; ?) Xaml is interesting to see.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're written should be fine. It depends on what `TaskViewMode` is and how it works.

Assuming that it is based on the `MainViewModel` in the default Pivot project template. Are you calling `LoadData()` on it to populate the Items Collection?